# Odoo 11 variantes de un producto por CSV: no asigna a todas la referencia interna por columna default_code

Tags: odoo

Estoy tratando de importar 9000 productos que tienen atributos de talla y color. Existen una media de 28 variantes de producto por cada uno, sumando unos 9000.

Cuando Odoo recibe una importación así:

name              id    default_code roduct_variant_ids/attribute_value_ids 
Dextrógiro-levógiro 20313931 20313931_multicolor-unica  multicolor,unica
Dextrógiro-levógiro n-m 20313931    1001032900_negro-m      negro,m 
Dextrógiro-levógiro a-l 20313931    1001032900_azul-l       blanco,m

Origina tres variantes, pero sólo a la primera le pone referencia interna. Sólo es posible buscar por nombre y barcode, pero no todas las variantes tienen asignada la referencia interna por la columna default_code, como se puede ver en la foto.. ¿ alguien sabe porqué las variantes subidas sólo son identificadas por barcode y name exclusivamente ?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el archivo que estás usando para importar es separado por tabuladores pero, como no se distinguen bien en una página web, me tomé la libertad de reescribirlo en formato separado por comas:

```
name,id,default_code,product_variant_ids/attribute_value_ids
Dextrógiro-levógiro,20313931,20313931_multicolor-unica,"multicolor,unica"
Dextrógiro-levógiro n-m,20313931,1001032900_negro-m,"negro,m"
Dextrógiro-levógiro a-l,20313931,1001032900_azul-l,"blanco,m"
```

Si me quedó bien la reescritura, veo que la columna `id` contiene el mismo valor en los tres renglones y eso es un problema porque la cabecera `id` le dice a Odoo que la columna contiene `xmlids` y éstos deben de ser únicos.

Así como está el archivo, al leer el primer renglón Odoo interpreta que su `xmlid` es `tu_modulo.20313931` y, si no existe un registro con ese identificador externo, lo crea mediante un comando SQL INSERT; luego, lee el segundo renglón y vuelve a interpretar que su `xmlid` es `tu_modulo.20313931` y por lo tanto ya existe, así que en vez de insertar un nuevo renglón lo que hace es actualizar con un comando SQL UPDATE el renglón anterior.

[Editado para agregar lo siguiente]

```
name,id,default_code,product_variant_ids/attribute_value_ids
Dextrógiro-levógiro,product_20313931_multicolor_unica,20313931_multicolor-unica,"multicolor,unica"
Dextrógiro-levógiro n-m,product_20313931_negro_m,1001032900_negro-m,"negro,m"
Dextrógiro-levógiro a-l,product_20313931_azul_l,1001032900_azul-l,"blanco,m"
```

Comment: Está muy bien tu explicación si no se generaran tres variantes. Explícame entonces porqué no hace continuamente UPDATES relacionales y me deja sólo un producto con la última variante propagada, porque sobreescribe el UPDATE los atributos contínuamente.

Comment: Además, si lo tienes tan claro, si crees que la id debe de ser única... cómo vas a poder recoger en un sólo producto la propagación de al menos 28 variantes, si no tienes una relación por ID. Lo de xmlid te lo sacas de la bragueta, más que de la manga, porque no tiene nada que ver a nivel relacional que me uses un prefijo que indique presencia en una estructura xnl o una mera relación id.